# Why is the gnuplot epslatex tex file yielding doubled axis/labels/key in different fonts

Tags: graphics, gnuplot

When using the gnuplot epslatex terminal the associated TeX file creates overlapping plot text (axis/key/labels). The eps file is as expected.

As the user is not supposed to worry about the generated gnuplot TeX file, I am at a loss as to what the problem is.

I have tried the epslatex monochrome option to no avail as with specifying the encoding in gnuplot TeX and main TeX document. Reinstalled both MiKTeX and gnuplot (5.4 level 6) several times. Ran code with TeXmaker, Overleaf and TeXworks with same results.

gnuplot with size change that illustrates issue

```
set terminal push
set terminal epslatex size 10,5 cm
#set terminal wxt
set output 'Run3DimC.tex'
#
f(x) = 1/(2*sqrt(pi*d))*exp(-1*(1-x)**2/(4*d))
fit f(x) "Run3.dat" using 1:2 via d
set xlabel "Dimensionless Time"
set ylabel "Dimensionless Concentration" 
set xrange [0:2]
set yrange [0:4]
plot    "Run3.dat" using 1:2 linetype 7 linecolor -1 title "Run 3",\
    f(x) lc -1 title "Fit"
set output
set terminal pop
pause -1 "Hit return to continue"
#
#  Clean up: reset parameter defaults
#
reset
```

TeX main document

```
    \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
    \usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{color}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    %\includegraphics{Run3DimC.eps}
    \input{Run3DimC.tex}
    \input{DULfitted.tex}
    \caption{Please work}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

I have uninstalled MikTeX and TeXmaker. I have now installed TeXlive and TeXworks. I now get an error message.

```
`[1{c:/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3]
(./NH3MM.tex)
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.131 \end{figure}`
```

It seems to be a font mapping issue.

[Diagram with gnuplot size 10,5 cm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U7NI.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Terminal standalone is a good tip, but I have not been able to narrowed down the issue. The unwanted text in the graph appears to be part of the preamble (minimal is now printed along with pdftexgeometry). The double printing with offset (seeing double effect) has disappeared without me knowing why.

Comment: "Standalone" produces a correct diagram with TeX labels/axis/key. In the most simplest of main TeX documents, with usepackage{color} although all in black, the eps file is correctly given. The x-axis is also correctly given, but the y-axis, xlabel, ylabel and key are all printed twice with a small offset  (double vision).

Comment: Are you still inputting both DULfitted.tex and Run3DimC.tex in your document?  Could it be that both of these contain axis labels and so you are seeing the superposition of both files?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the keyword `standalone` to the terminal specification in gnuplot it will produce a minimal *.tex document that contains the necessary package loads etc at the top.   You can inspect these to see what your actual document might be missing.  In this case the head of the file gnuplot emits with `set terminal epslatex standalone` is

```
 % GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\documentclass{minimal}
% Set font size
\makeatletter
\def\@ptsize{1}
\InputIfFileExists{size11.clo}{}{%
   \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Gnuplot Error: File `size11.clo' not found! Could not set font size%
   }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
   }{For using a font size a file `size<fontsize>.clo' has to exist.
        Falling back ^^Jto default fontsize 10pt.}%
  \def\@ptsize{0}
  \input{size10.clo}%
}%
\makeatother
% Load packages
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
```

I don't quite follow your description of what your output looked like, but it sounds like maybe you need at the least `\usepackage{color}`?